# Is there a way to cancel a search in Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, searching

Is there a way to cancel a word search in Mathematica initiated via the Find and Replace menu?

Comment: Kill the front end is one way.  You'll lose all unsaved work, though.

Comment: On macOS, while the Find dialog is running, hitting the esc key closes the dialog which stops the search. Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm running Mathematica 11.3.0.0 on 64-bit Windows 10 and unfortunately the esc key doesn't work for me. It can take several minutes to search a large file, and its frustrating to wait for a search to complete when I realize the search term is incorrect. I know how to gracefully abort an evaluation from the keyboard, and it seems to me there should be a way to gracefully abort a search from the keyboard (without killing the application and losing your work).

Comment: How large are your files / slow is your computer that it can take several minutes? That's worrisome.

Comment: @user6014 My PC has an i5-4590 CPU with 8 GB RAM and a WD 1 TB hard drive. I have about 100 workbooks. The largest is about 167 MB and there are several workbooks around 100 MB in size. I tend to spend most of my time in the larger workbooks which probably explains why they're so large.